# You want your type to be able to be converted from string. Which interface should you implement?

Tags: .net

The answer in Exam Ref 70-483 (Wouter de Kort) is "IFormattable". 
Explanation in the book is "*IFormattable provides the functionality to format the value of an object
into a string representation(**I'm agree with this part**). It is also used by the Convert class to do the opposite.*"

How **Convert** can create an object from a string? It doesn't have FromString (it has ChangeType but still). More interesting, how could IFormattable facilitate in conversation FROM string?

I sincerely think that the question is not valid but want to be sure.

Comment: I think you are right, but I don't know how to answer properly :)